# $n$-th order derivatives of multivariable composites

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have smooth functions $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. Is there a nice expression for the $n$-th derivative of $f \circ g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ in terms of the (partial) derivatives of $f$ and $g$? Heck, even if it's not nice I'd still be interested to see a formula. Thanks for any advice, and sorry to post such a mechanical question!

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted this, but if it was one of the answerers: I appreciate your response, but you haven't provided a complete answer in one way or another, so I haven't ticked you. Ending posts with "moral" or "overall" is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Well not in term of partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$ but is think the well-known [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) could help you.

$$(f\circ g)^{(n)}(x)=\sum \frac{n!}{m_1!\,1!^{m_1}\,m_2!\,2!^{m_2}\,\cdots\,m_n!\,n!^{m_n}}\cdot f^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(g(x))\cdot \prod_{j=1}^n\left(g^{(j)}(x)\right)^{m_j},$$

where the sum is over all $n$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(m_1, \dots, m_n)$ satisfying the constraint $1\cdot m_1+2\cdot m_2+3\cdot m_3+\cdots+n\cdot m_n=n.\,$

You can read about the multivariate version of the formula in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965903900267). Also [this](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Johnson217-234.pdf) could be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The expression will be ugly, but you can find it using the chain rule. For example, the first derivative is (if $g(x) = (g_1(x), g_2(x), g_3(x))$)

$$(f\circ g)'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(g(x))\cdot g_1'(x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(g(x))\cdot g_s'(x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}(g(x))\cdot g_3'(x)$$

which is already a fairly ugly expression. Finding the second derivative will mean that each of the three expressions $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(g(x))\cdot g_i'(x)$ will again explode into three other expressions, and you will also have to deal with the derivative of a product.

Overall: If at all possible, try to simplify the expression $f(g(x))$ and find the derivative of that.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of calculating partial derivative you may assume all of the functions involved to be analytic that is they can be expressed as power series locally. The series expansion is given by the Taylor formula, that is 
$$f(x_0+s) = f(x_0) + \sum_{|\alpha|>0} \frac{\partial^{\alpha }f}{\alpha!}(x_0)\cdot s^{\alpha} $$
Now instead of $x_0 + s$ plug in $g(y_0+t)$ which itself has a power series expansion
$$g(y_0+t) = g(y_0) + \sum_{|\beta|>0} \frac{\partial^{\beta }g}{\beta!}(y_0)\cdot t^{\beta} $$
Plug in the first equality $x_0 + s= g(y_0+t) = g(y_0) + \ldots$ and so $x_0= g(y_0)$ and 
$s = \sum_{|\beta|>0} \frac{\partial^{\beta }g}{\beta!}(y_0)\cdot t^{\beta} $. Transform it into a series in $t$. Then match it with the expansion of $f\circ g$ at $y_0$.

Moral: the Taylor expansion from functions to series is a morphism. It works for sums, products, compositions, inverses...